# Spring MVC: How to deal with form processing / model binding of many hundred thousand to million of entries in table

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, binding

I'm having a problem to display a list of entries in table using Spring MVC. Each entry in the table can be change by the users.

There is a submit button inside a form, which action is wired to a Spring controller to process the changed rows.

The default limit of Spring form binding is known to 256 entries, which can be easily extended by changing the autoGrowCollectionLimit. But it won't scale, when we have the amount of entries as multiple of thousand.

My goals are the following:

1. Deal with showing and text-filtering (on the fly) million of entries. Can bootstrap-table be used in this case? I tried bootstrap-table, but it needs data to be fed in as json. I have then problem with binding changed entries in Spring form!
2. Submit only changed entries to the controller. The user can change the first entry and then the millionth one, and then submit the form! etc...

Any hints, ideas or examples on how to deal with this kind of problem are appreciated! Even a move to new technology needed!